Equivalence about prime ideals.
Could you give me some ideas or hints that the latter two things are equivalent? 
$R$ is a commutative ring, and $I$ is a subset of $R$. 
・　$\forall f,g\in R, fg\in I \Longrightarrow f\in I\vee g\in I$ 
・　$\forall J,K:$ ideals of $R$, $JK\subset I \Longrightarrow J\subset I\vee K\subset I$

Is either of the directions clear to you?  It's good to get an easy direction out of the way first. (Hint: principal ideals.)
